# How to convert base-10 (decimal) to base-2 (binary) in Scratch?

Tags: delphi, binary, decimal, mit-scratch, base-conversion

I have the following function written in the Delphi Programming Language that converts a base-10 (decimal) number to a base-2 (binary) number:

```
function DecimalToBinary(Value: Int64): string;
const
  tt: array [0 .. 1] of char = ('0', '1');
begin
  Result := '';
  var i: Int64 := Value;
  if i = 0 then Result := '0'
  else
    while (i <> 0) do
    begin
      Result := tt[(i and $1)] + Result;
      i := (i shr 1);
    end;
end;
```

How can I replicate this function in [Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/)?

I want to be able to convert a base-10 (decimal) number to a base-2 (binary) in Scratch.

Comment: Why declaring `i` when you could operate on `Value` directly? Why setting the result to `''` instead of doing only when `Value<> 0`? Would a negative `Value` run it endlessly?

Comment: That's a very inefficient Delphi function BTW.

Comment: The question is expressed in a slightly misleading way. This is not about converting _from_ a decimal representation; this is only about converting _to_ a binary representation.

Comment: @RuudHelderman Sorry, but what do you mean?

Comment: He means that "_binary_" mostly means bytes, f.e. decimal `268` would be in binary **form** `#$0c#$01` (or in hexadecimal `$10c` **representation**). "[_Binary_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file)" as in what your compiler produces with an .EXE or .DLL.

Comment: Shaun, I guess @Ruud referred to the fact that, as the input to `DecimalToBinary()` is an `Int64` it has nothing to do with conversion **from** decimal.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Correct. `Value` is not a decimal number. In fact, when doing math on integer numbers, it's irrelevant in what base the number is stored. Delphi statements `Value := 256;`, `Value := $100;` and `Value := %100000000;` are equivalent; it's always the same number. If anything, I'd say `Value` is binary. Delphi function `DecimalToBinary` is actually taking advantage of the fact that `Value` is stored in a binary format (`and` and `shr` are bitwise operators). But even if it would use `div` and `mod` on some BCD-type variable, it's still nowhere near 'a conversion from decimal.'

Comment: What would be a more accurate title then? I've modified it now, but what would be the best title then that isn't misleading?

Comment: Shaun, it's like you did not really get what @Ruud and I have tried to point out. Your `function DecimalToBinary(Value: Int64): string;` is not limited to only decimal (or base-10) input. Yes, you can write 's := DecimalToBinary(100);' and the "100" represents the decimal value hundred, but you could equally write s := DecimalToBinary($64), where "$64" is a hex value, or you could write 's := DecimalToBinary(%01100100);', where "%01100100" is a binary value, and get exactly the same string ("100") in return. (cont...)

Comment: (... cont) Likewise, if you supply a variable, it may be any type that is assignment compatible with Int64. Therefore the word that represents the input could and should be "integer" (or "int") as that is the type required by the function. Then again, as the output is a string, and specifically a binary string, that part of the name of the function could be "binStr". Conclusion: **function IntToBinStr(Value: Int64): string;**

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I found a couple of [sample projects](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/11888242/remixes/) as well as a [tutorial](https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Binary_Conversion) on how to convert decimal to binary in Scratch.

Thanks to the above two links, I was able to create a function in Scratch that converts decimal numbers to binary numbers.

First I created two variables named "binary" and "i":

[image: Scratch variables]

And then I created my own code block (function) that uses the variables and does the conversion:

[image: Scratch Decimal to Binary Code Block]

Using this new code block, I'm able to convert from decimal to binary:

[image: Scratch Decimal to Binary Code Block]

Comment: Must `i` be declared or could you operate on `decimal` directly? What is returned with `0` as input - an empty text? What about negative numbers? Why screenshots with such a high resolution (1989 x 1797 px for the second one)?

Comment: @AmigoJack `i` must be declared. You can't operate directly on `decimal`. Scratch doesn't allow you to modify the `decimal` value within your code block. I added an if statement to handle `0` as input. Thanks.